# How do I simulate a click event in VB Windows Forms

Tags: vb.net, events

I just want to connect two arbitrary controls, so that if one is clicked, the other should act as though it's clicked - is this even remotely possible? it seems like it SHOULD be so easy, but the internet seems dry, unless I just don't know how to ask the question properly... I see a way to "click" a button control, but what if the target is not a button? - I don't know the name of any function that might be triggered by this control's click event, so I can't call it directly. I would guess there is some way of using Windows APIs, but I can't find anything that's nice, simple VB

Example

I click a Label control on the form. I want to handle that click event, run one line of code, then simulate a click event on an associated RadioButton control

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must, call (System.Windows.Forms.Controls.)Control.InvokeOnClick

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokeonclick%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

or even RadioButton.PerformClick

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.performclick.aspx

Comment: why do you say "if you must"? It would seem the internet agrees, as I could not find anyone recommending it, but its not deprecated, so what's the downside of using it?

Comment: It's about separation of UI and program layout.  If all you really want is radio buttons that have labels you can click on, that's why the radio button classes have a Text property.

A cardinal sin I'm dealing with at my day job is "form-driven design", where significant amounts of program code is hidden in the event handlers of a legacy windows program.  This makes it hard to discover, difficult to debug, and impossible to automatically test.

It's better to use events to trigger program code, if for no other reason that it frees you to re-design the UI latter.

Comment: in my case - which seems to be creating a program you'd hate to crack open - I have textboxes that are rendered as labels (TabStop false, etc) until Ctrl+clicked, at which point they become editable.  if clicked without Ctrl, I would prefer they act like they are part of another control, like a normal textbox or a radio button. (it's a personal interest program, so chances of you being bridled with it are practically non-existent)

Comment: So they're not labels, they're textboxes.  Neat.  That's all proper UI interaction anyway, so I wouldn't have a problem with it meself.  :)  (might I suggest that, instead of writing the same method for each control, you add a "target" property to a general textbox class and re-use?)

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be to create a common Subroutine that would be called on click of either controls. This way clicking on controls will execute their own code which can differ, and some common code as well.

Comment: This would not handle other eventhandlers attached to the target control, though, and probably some other things - if its not possible, its not possible - I just hope someone knows otherwise

Answer (score 0):

This is how you accomplish executing the same code regardless of which control event was fired.

```
Private Sub ClickMe()
  'code to execute
End Sub

Private Sub label1_Click(...) ...
   ClickMe()
End Sub

Private Sub rb_checked(...) ...
   ClickMe()
End Sub
```